# Instant location in AsyncTask with LocationListener and HttpUrlConnection post data

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, locationlistener

It has been a while I'm getting to solve out this problem.

I have an AsyncTask which is getting every 20s the network location of the user and post the data to a remote server.

I have requested permissions as shown belong

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Here is the OnCreate() of the MainActivitiy and the rest of the code

```
public class TraficMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new UrlPositionAsynck().execute();
    }

    private class UrlPositionAsynck extends AsyncTask<Void, Void , String> {

        public double longitude, latitude;
        public URL url;
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... urlink) {

            GPSPosition gpsPosition = new GPSPosition(TraficMain.this);

            locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 20000, 0, gpsPosition);

            Position position = gpsPosition.getPosition();

            String params= "lb_lo=" + position.getLb_longitude() + "&lb_la=" + position.getLb_latitude();

            try {
                url = new URL("http://myremote_url");
                byte[] param=params.getBytes("UTF-8");
                int postLength=param.length;
                HttpURLConnection strConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                strConn.setDoOutput(true);
                strConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
                strConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                strConn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
                strConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                strConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                strConn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
                strConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postLength ));
                strConn.setUseCaches( false );
                OutputStream out=strConn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter data =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(strConn.getOutputStream()));
                data.write(params);
                data.flush();
                data.close();
                out.flush();
                out.close();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((strConn.getInputStream())));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String output;
                while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(output);
                }
            }catch(IOException io){
                Log.i("Connection Problem :", io.getMessage());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
}
```

And I get the location with this class that implements LocationListener

```
public class GPSPosition implements LocationListener{

    Activity myContext;
    public double longitude, latitude;

    public GPSPosition(Activity context){
        this.myContext=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();

        TextView txt = (TextView) this.myContext.findViewById(R.id.txtPosition);
        txt.setText(longitude + ", " + latitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    public Position getPosition(){
        return new Position(this.longitude, this.latitude);
    }
```

My problem with this code. I only posts data when the app is launched and the latitude and longitude are always equal to 0.

I was expecting to have data posted to the remote server every 20seconds.
Can somebody tells how to handler this to be solved ? I have been spending the whole weekend

**EDIT**
This the new code of the onCreate().
Even if the device changes the position, the value of the location are unchanged and I don't really know why this is happening.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final GPSPosition gpsPosition = new GPSPosition(TraficMain.this);

            locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, gpsPosition);
            new UrlPositionAsynck().execute(gpsPosition.getPosition());
        }
    }, 20000);
}

private class UrlPositionAsynck extends AsyncTask<Position, Void , String> {
    public double longitude, latitude;
    public URL url;
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Position... urlink) {

        Position position = urlink[0];

        String params= "lb_lo=" + position.getLb_longitude() + "&lb_la=" + position.getLb_latitude();

        try {
            url = new URL("http://remote_url");
            byte[] param=params.getBytes("UTF-8");
            int postLength=param.length;
            HttpURLConnection strConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            strConn.setDoOutput(true);
            strConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            strConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            strConn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            strConn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            strConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            strConn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
            strConn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( postLength ));
            strConn.setUseCaches( false );

            OutputStream out=strConn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter data =new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(strConn.getOutputStream()));
            data.write(params);
            data.flush();
            data.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((strConn.getInputStream())));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String output;
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(output);
            }
        }catch(IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you are executing your AsyncTask once.

Comment: Do you mean I should add a while Loop inside the doInBackGround ?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a handler and run it after every 20 seconds by doing something like this

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
new UrlPositionAsynck().execute();
       //Do something after 20 seconds
       handler.postDelayed(this, 20000);
   }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This peace of code was helpful. I can connect to the remote but the problem is still not solved. The value of the positions is unchanged

Comment: You are missing access coarse location permission in manifest